# transcendent equations with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am wondering about the number of possible real solutions of $x^{2}=a^{x}$ where $a<0$.

Rational solutions seem to exist only in intervals of the form $[2k-1,2k]$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ because $2k-1+1/m=(2km-m+1)/m$ and $m$ must clearly be odd, while the numerator must be even.

In the other intervals $m$ odd yields $n$ odd and there are no solutions.

We can also note that $a^{n/m}$ is always defined as long as $n$ and $m$ are coprime and $m$ is odd. This set of rational numbers is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but its complement too. Being hard to talk about continuity in an intuitive sense in this situation I am not completely sure that we can conclude that $a^{x}$ is defined on irrational values of $x$?

Also, the non existence of rational solutions in a given interval does not exclude the existence of irrational ones in it. And the possibility of existence of rational solutions in other intervals does not imply the existence either. To summarize, I think this problem should not be straightforward and I was wondering if some literature exists about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start discussing solutions for the equation $x^2=a^x$, you have to define carefully what you mean by $a^x$ for $a<0$. You have to resort to working in $\mathbb{C}$, the field of Complex Numbers, and there, this function is multivalued. There are exactly $k$ such functions for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and before you start you have to pick the one you are interested in. For example, you can define:

$$a_k^x=\exp(x(\ln(|a|+(\pi+2k\pi)i))),k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

using the Principal Branch of the Complex $\log$ map, where the principal argument of any negative number is clearly $\pi$.

Once you decide on which branch you want, you can check to see when (and if) the function will be real-valued. In general, you can see the following:

$$a_k^x\in\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\exp(x(\ln(|a|+(\pi+2k\pi)i)))\in\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\exp(x\ln(|a|))\exp(x(\pi+2k\pi)i)\in\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\exp(x\ln(|a|))(\cos(x(\pi+2k\pi))+i\sin(x(\pi+2k\pi)))\in\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\exp(x\ln(|a|))\sin(x(\pi+2k\pi))i=0\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x(\pi+2k\pi))=0\Leftrightarrow$$
$$x(\pi+2k\pi)=2\lambda\pi,\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$$

which finally gives:

$$x=\frac{2\lambda}{1+2k},k,\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$$

And the last one means that if you have defined your function as such, you can determine all $x$ where it will be real-valued. For example, if $k=1$, you get the set: $S=\{\ldots,-8/3,-2,-4/3,-2/3,0,2/3,4/3,2,8/3,\ldots\}$, and when $x\in S$, the map $a_1^x$ will be real-valued.

**Edit#1**

Such $x$ is necessary for the map to attain a real value, so we now force it to be a solution, so just plug this $x$ into the equation. This gives:

$$\left(\frac{2\lambda}{1+2k}\right)^2=a_k^{\frac{2\lambda}{1+2k}}$$

which according to the definition above resolves to:

$$\left(\frac{2\lambda}{1+2k}\right)^2=\exp\left(\frac{2\lambda}{1+2k}\ln(|a_k|)\right)$$

This imposes restrictions on $a_k$, so we now backtrack and solve for $a_k$. This is a little tedious, so I got (using Maple):

$$a=\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(-2\ln(2)+2\ln(-1-2k)-\ln(\lambda^2))(1+2k)}{\lambda}\right),-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(-2\ln(2)+2\ln(-1-2k)-\ln(\lambda^2))(1+2k)}{\lambda}\right)\right\},k<-1$$

and:

$$a=\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(-2\ln(2)+2\ln(-1-2k)-\ln(\lambda^2))(1+2k)}{\lambda}\right),-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(-2\ln(2)+2\ln(1+2k)-\ln(\lambda^2))(1+2k)}{\lambda}\right)\right\},k>-1$$

The first members of the two sets are rejected, since they are obviously positive. The second members after lots of tedious calculations (again using Maple) simplify to:

$$a=-2^{\frac{1}{\lambda}}4^{\frac{k}{\lambda}}(-1-2k)^{\frac{1+2k}{\lambda}}(\lambda^2)^{\frac{1+2k}{2\lambda}},k<-1 (1)$$

and:

$$a=-2^{\frac{1}{\lambda}}4^{\frac{k}{\lambda}}(1+2k)^{\frac{1+2k}{\lambda}}(\lambda^2)^{\frac{1+2k}{2\lambda}},k>-1 (2)$$

Checking some values with Maple:

[image]

[image]

```
                    1   (4/5)   (9/10)
                  - -- 2      25      
                    50                
                    1   (3/4)   (7/8)
                  - -- 2      16     
                    32               
                     1   (2/3)  (5/6)
                   - -- 2      9     
                     18              
                     1  (1/2)  (3/4)
                   - - 2      4     
                     8              
                           -1
                           --
                           2 
                           -2
                       (1/2)  (1/4)
                     -2      4     
                       (1/3)  (1/6)
                     -2      9     
                      (1/4)   (1/8)
                    -2      16     
                      (1/5)   (1/10)
                    -2      25
```

Concluding, if, for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a=a_k<0$ is of one of two forms (1), (2) above, the equation $x^2=a^x$ admits infinately many solutions given by $x=\frac{2\lambda}{2k+1}$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$. If, $a$ is not of the form (1) or (2), then the equation has no real solution, since the map $a^x$ in general will be Complex valued.

Note: Big fuss for $a<0$. For $a>0$ the equation is solved trivially using the Lambert $W$ function.